# How to add middle IDs in third table with ManyToManyField in Django when using Serialaizer?

Tags: python, django, model, django-serializer, manytomanyfield

I have tables like this:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(default=None)
    price = models.ManyToManyField(Price)

class Price(models.Model):
    cost = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=20)
```

And from client get a request and try to save it in **three** tables, I have no problem with two tables `Education` and `Price` but because I'm using **serializer** i don't know how to update third table(middle).

```
def post(self, request):
    cost = request.POST.get('cost')
    price = Price.objects.create(cost=cost)

    education_serializer = EducationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if education_serializer.is_valid():
        education_serializer.save()
```

Good, here i have updated two tables, In the following i don't know how update third table. If i didn't use serializer i have could write it like this:

```
education.price.add(price)
```

Comment: Please share your serializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `education_serializer.save` returns an instance of `Education`, so you can write:

```py
def post(self, request):
    cost = request.POST.get('cost')
    price = Price.objects.create(cost=cost)

    education_serializer = EducationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if education_serializer.is_valid():
        education = education_serializer.save()
        education.price.add(price)
```